# Select Multiple com jQuery Chosen

Tags: jquery, razor, html-select

Tenho uma classe **Cliente**, e uma classe **Sistema**
Meu **cliente**  pode ter mais de um **sistema**, e um **sistema**, pode ter mais de um **cliente**.

Tenho um capo select Multiple, na minha view editar, que carrega os **sistemas** que meu **cliente** usa.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e se eu clicar sobre o campo, ele mostra os **sistemas** que meu **cliente** usa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

só que a realidade, é que eu queria apresentar os **sistemas** que meu **cliente** usa, já selecionado.  dessa maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu uso o Razor, então esse é o código do select:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("SistemasComerciais", new SelectList(ViewBag.SistemasComerciais, "Id", "Descricao"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "standardSelect", multiple = "multiple", placeholder = "Selecione..." })
```

E esse é o código Html que gera.

```
<select class="standardSelect" id="SistemasComerciais" multiple="multiple" name="SistemasComerciais" placeholder="Selecione..." style="display: none;">
<option value="1">CT-e</option>
<option value="2">MERCHANT</option>
</select>

<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" title="" id="SistemasComerciais_chosen" style="width: 100%;"><ul class="chosen-choices">
  <li class="search-field">
    <input class="chosen-search-input default" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="Select Some Options" style="width: 179px;">
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <ul class="chosen-results">
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0">CT-e</li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">MERCHANT</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Alguém poderia me falar como eu faço para que os sistemas já venham selecionado?
eu uso esse plugin, para funionar o select Multiple:

```
<script src="~/Template/vendors/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Se alguém, souber, pelo menos um tutoria, artigo, qualquer coisa, na qual contenha uma explicação para como eu possa fazer isso, já seria de grande ajuda!

Comment: esses dados do tipo de sistema, fica salvo no banco? para mostrar você puxa do banco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de chamar o `.chosen()`, coloque o atributo `selected` em todos os options do select:

```js
$("#SistemasComerciais")
.find("option")
.prop("selected", true)
.end()
.chosen();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="standardSelect" id="SistemasComerciais" multiple="multiple" name="SistemasComerciais" placeholder="Selecione..." style="width: 100%;">
   <option value="1">CT-e</option>
   <option value="2">MERCHANT</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Simplesmente Perfeito!!! bati tanta cabeça, e no final parecia tão fácil!